# Change default font dialog in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can anyone tell me how can set default Font Name , Font Size , Font Color.. of FontDialog;

```
 FontDialog dlg = new FontDialog();
            dlg.ShowColor = true;
  if (dlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
```

The  dlg.ShowDialog() ; method should show Font name that I choose insted of "microsoft san serif"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to set the `Font` property before calling `ShowDialog`.

For example:

```
dlg.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10);
//or
dlg.Font = myCurrentlySelectedFont;
```

Comment: What about Underline and strikeout properties

Comment: `var myFont = new Font("Consolas",10); 
 myFont.Underline=true;
 dlg.Font = myFont`

Comment: abhilash - Underline is read only. I think Lanke was asking how to allow for underline and strikeout... or in other words how do you set the FontFamily without specifying a very specific set of font properties

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth pointing out that when getting the font name from the font dialog, you want the value: `fontDlg.Font.Name`, or `fontDlg.Font.FontFamily.Name`.

This value will correctly allow you to set the font name as above before showing the dialogue.